# php - MySQli row count always returning 0?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

`rowLogin` is always returning `0`? but when i run the query on sql i get the correct outcome! I've had a look at loads of solutions but literally none are working.

```
$queryLogin =("SELECT count(*) as count FROM `tblUser` WHERE `username` = '$username' and `password` ='$password'");
$resultLogin = $mysqli->query($queryLogin);
$rowLogin = $resultLogin->fetch_assoc();

echo $rowLogin['count']." rows in table tblUser.";
```

Comment: Look at my answer. It should help you get the answer. If you don't like the prepared statement route just look at the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not very good...

You really need to be using MYSQLi prepared statements esp with username / pass checks...

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);
$query = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM `tblUser` WHERE `username`=? and `password`=?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$username,$password);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if($result->num_rows){
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo $row['count'] . " rows in table tblUser.";
}
```

I understand you are potentially looking into just getting some information, but this is the best route to take so move this way. Do not continue in your path.

It is very likely that your query failed because you have `( )` around your actually query. So if you want to use that just get rid of the `( )` on the line with `$queryLogin`.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$queryLogin =("SELECT count(*) as count FROM tblUser WHERE username = '".$username."' and password ='".$password."' ");
$resultLogin = $mysqli->query($queryLogin);
$rowLogin = $resultLogin->fetch_assoc();

echo $rowLogin['count']." rows in table tblUser.";

or

printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($resultLogin));
```

Comment: Ok, so what did you do that's different and explain why? Let's all learn something ;-)

Comment: Protip: When you give an explanation as to why a person's code fails, you stand to get (more) upvotes for it. Keep that in mind the next time you answer a question, you'll thank me for it.

Comment: The main reason query doesn't work because of scopes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need scopes.

```
$queryLogin = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM `tblUser` WHERE `username` = '$username' and `password` ='$password'";
$resultLogin = $mysqli->query($queryLogin);
$rowLogin = $resultLogin->fetch_assoc();

echo $rowLogin['count']." rows in table tblUser.";
```

Only use scope in inline query.
You already using scopes here...

```
$resultLogin = $mysqli->query($queryLogin);
```