# Checking for record in MySQL and create if not exist

Tags: php, mysql

When I click a buy now button I'm checking to see if the record (product id) exists in my mysql database table and if they don't create another one and if they do, just update the existing one.

It creates the first record fine and it even updates when I click it again without making another record, but when I click another product it creates another record and it never updates the following records.

In other words it just updates the first product id and it creates new records for the rest.

here is an image of my table [image]

```html
function add_to_cart(){

global $connection;

$ip = getIp();



if(isset($_GET['add'])) {

$product_id = $_GET['id'];
$product_price = get_item_price($product_id);


$query = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE ip_address = '{$ip}' ";
$check_query = query($query);
confirm($check_query);
$row = fetch_array($check_query);
$db_product_id = $row['product_id'];

if(mysqli_num_rows($check_query) === 0 || $product_id != $db_product_id)  {

$query = "INSERT INTO cart(product_id,ip_address,quantity,price_sum) VALUES('{$product_id}', '{$ip}' ,1, '{$product_price}')";

$send_query_cart = query($query);
confirm($send_query_cart);
redirect("index.php");

} else {

$query = "UPDATE cart SET quantity = quantity + 1, price_sum = price_sum + '{$product_price}' WHERE product_id = '{$product_id}' ";
$update_records = query($query);
confirm($update_records);
redirect("index.php");



}




}








}
```

Comment: Sorry, I did, I had my caps on and did not noticed much....

Comment: instead of `die("QUERY FAILED");` do `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` and see if you get errors.

Comment: Yes I' m doing that also...I don't get any errors.

Comment: I'm in XXAMP error_reporting is on . I have it set from the php.ini

Comment: I tried posting an image of table here but I can't until I get my reputation points.  My tables looks like this .... id (PRIMARY) and AUTO increment then product_id , ip_address, quantity, price_sum

Comment: Ok I posted an image of my table so you can get an idea.

Comment: Can you show your `$check_query` query?  I am assuming you are seeing if the same product id exists for a given ip address, and you are using ip_address to identify the user?

Comment: if(isset($_GET['add'])) {

$product_id = $_GET['id'];
$product_price = get_item_price($product_id);


$query = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE ip_address = '{$ip}' ";
$check_query = query($query);
confirm($check_query);
$row = fetch_array($check_query);
$db_product_id = $row['product_id'];

Comment: I'm using custom functions like query() for mysqli_query() and so on, I know my logic must be bad somewhere.

Comment: Just updated code above to reflect the entire function. Please check, thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [php - MySQli row count always returning 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640470/php-mysqli-row-count-always-returning-0)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution is to create a `UNIQUE` constraint on (I am assuming) `product_id` and `ip_address`.

```
ALTER TABLE `cart` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`ip_address`, `product_id`);
```

Then, I would not store the price of items in the cart at all.  The price of an item can be looked up in your items table.  When an order is completed you can save the price of the individual item since it could change, but while it's in the cart you want the most recent price.

Once you have done that, your query can be simplified to

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cart(product_id,ip_address,quantity)
              VALUES ('{$product_id}', '{$ip}', 1) 
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
              quantity = quantity+1";
```

and you don't even have to check it - the query will handle the update or insert automatically.

Also, I wouldn't rely on ip_address to identify users - if someone is shopping on their phone while riding in a car, it could easily change.  Two people on the same router can appear to have the same ip address to your website.  I would save something in the session or in a secure cookie and use that to identify them.

To get the totals, you would do something like:

```
$totals = "SELECT cart.product_id, cart.quantity * products.price as product_price_total
           FROM cart
           LEFT JOIN products USING(products.id = cart.product_id)
           WHERE ip_address = '{$ip}'";
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, How do I create a constraint, in phpmyadmin?  I need to put this in a function but don't know much about constraints yet.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE `cart` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`ip_address`, `product_id`);`

Comment: What mean what was, if that ALTER TABLE cart ADD UNIQUE unique_index(ip_address, product_id) is goes in phpmyadmin query window? or I can send it with       $query = "ALTER TABLE cart ADD UNIQUE unique_index(ip_address, product_id)";
$alter_table = query($query);

Comment: oh, yeah you could just do that once in the phpmyadmin query window

Comment: function add_to_cart(){


$ip = getIp();

if(isset($_GET['add'])){
$product_id = $_GET['id'];


$query = "INSERT INTO cart(product_id,ip_address,quantity) VALUES ('{$product_id}', '{$ip}', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity+1 WHERE product_id = '{$product_id}' AND ip_address = '{$ip}' ";

$result_set = query($query );
confirm($result_set);

}

}

Comment: I get this error   QUERY FAILED You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE product_id = '2' AND ip_address = '::1'' at line 1

Comment: Sorry you can remove the whole WHERE clause since its in the on duplicate key part